# Why reverse lookup is not done to validate ssl cert against IP?

Tags: ssl-certificate, ip-address

I have a ssl cert generated for "host1.domain.com". This host has 4 NIC configured. 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12 and 192.168.1.13 are the IPs. Now, if I try to browse through IP, it gives cert mismatch and works fine with hostname as expected. Why doesn't it do a lookup to validate the certificate against ip?